# Difference between "*=" and "=" in css

Tags: css

What is the difference between "*=" and just "=" in CSS?

e.g.

```
a[href=#team]
```

and

```
a[href*=#team]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting the CSS Selectors Level 3 specification:

> `[att=val]`
>
> > Represents an element with the att attribute whose value is exactly "val".
>
> `[att*=val]`
>
> > Represents an element with the att attribute whose value contains at least one instance of the substring "val". If "val" is the empty string then the selector does not represent anything.

Reference:

- [CSS attribute-selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors).

Answer (score 1):

`a[href="#team"]` matches the href exactly (`<a href="#team">`).

`a[href*="#team"]` applies to `href`s where `#team` occurs, but may only be a part of the `href`-value (i.e. contained within it). `a[href*="#team"]` would match this link: `<a href="page.html#team-list">`).

Answer (score 1):

See the official reference on [http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors)

`E[foo="bar"]`  - an E element whose "foo" attribute value is exactly equal to "bar"

`E[foo*="bar"]` - an E element whose "foo" attribute value contains the substring "bar"

There are also some other like

`E[foo^="bar"]` - an E element whose "foo" attribute value begins exactly with the string "bar"

`E[foo~="bar"]` - an E element whose "foo" attribute value is a list of whitespace-separated values, one of which is exactly equal to "bar"

So `a[href=#team]` matches only `<a href="#team">` but `a[href*=#team]` also matches e.g. `<a href="site.html#team">`

Answer (score 0):

First one targets href which is  "exactly" equal to the value while the second one targets  href which just "contains" the value.

Answer (score 0):

`a[href='#team']` matches exactly href `#team`

`a[href*='#team']` matches href contain `#team`

> **Note:** There should be "quote" when selecting element

```
a[href*='#team']
        ^     ^ ========> required
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/k634grgf/)

Answer (score 0):

The '=' refers to an exact match for the term you are searching for

The '*=' means 'contains' the term you are searching for